# Codeigniter 3.0: File name is not changing after uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am uploading images and files through a form. But after the upload the name is not changing. On first function call if the name is i.e profilePic then this file name remains same on every call even i am changing the name in $config['file_name'] parameter.

Function calls:

```
    function getAndSaveEmployeeDetails() {
    $resume = 'resume';
    $resume = $this -> do_upload($resume, $employeeID);

    $profilePic = 'profilePic';
    $profilePic = $this -> do_upload($profilePic, $employeeID);

    $cnic = 'cnicScannedImage';
    $cnicScannedImage = $this -> do_upload($cnic, $employeeID); }
```

//upload function

```
public function do_upload($uploadedField, $employeeID) {
//$uploadedField = $this -> input -> post('_hidden_field');
    if (empty($_FILES[$uploadedField]['name'])) {

        $error = "File is empty please choose a file";
        return $error;

    } else {
        $name = '_' . $uploadedField;
        $config['file_name'] = $employeeID . $name;
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/' . $employeeID;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|iso|dmg|zip|rar|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|csv|ods|odt|odp|pdf|rtf|sxc|sxi|txt|exe|avi|mpeg|mp3|mp4|3gp';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $config['max_width'] = 0;
        $config['max_height'] = 0;
        $this -> load -> library('upload', $config);

        if (!is_dir('uploads')) {
            mkdir('./uploads', 0777, true);
        }
        $dir_exist = true;
        // flag for checking the directory exist or not
        if (!is_dir('uploads/' . $employeeID)) {
            mkdir('./uploads/' . $employeeID, 0777, true);
            $dir_exist = false;
            // dir not exist
        } else {

        }

        if (!$this -> upload -> do_upload($uploadedField)) {

            if (!$dir_exist)
                rmdir('./uploads/' . $employeeID);

            $error = array('error' => $this -> upload -> display_errors());
            return $error;

            //$this -> load -> view('upload_form', $error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this -> upload -> data());

            return $path = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];

        }
    }
}
```

Please look at the image in the below link you will understand the behavior

[These are the file names and it is caching the first name passed in function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvf7B.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `upload` library in the first line of `getAndSaveEmployeeDetails()`, using

`$this->load->library('upload');`

without passing any config.

Then in `do_upload($uploadedField, $employeeID)` function after defining your config array, don't use `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`
but use `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: Thanks Its working. Can you please tell me the difference between
$this->load->library('upload', $config); vs $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: The upload library was initialized with a config in the first function call which has resume as `$uploadedField`. In the other function calls, the upload library won't be loaded because it is already. The trick is to load it without any config then initialize it with a config specific to each function call.